yarn run build making build with missing functionalities
i am facing strange yarn run build behavior, when I execute yarn run dev with laravel APP_ENV=product it works fine but where i execute yarn run dev with APP_ENV=local it miss functionalities like drop down not working and search bar not  appearing etc.
With this logic, it should build error-free with APP_ENV=production but no, it build with same errors i describe with local with 'yarn run dev
I can't understand this strange behavior, My tech stack is Laravel, vue3, inertia, and SSR.
laravel 10
node 18.17.1
yarn 1.22.22
APP_NAME=TEST
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:/KQKTkSiWjKx4aSrNGS0SP8CBF7+P49+5/Dw9JijfBo=
APP_DEBUG=true

APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8008

my package.json file

{
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production vite build && vite build --ssr",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore --fix src",
    "format": "prettier .  --write",
    "mix-development": "mix",
    "mix-watch": "mix watch",
    "mix-watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "mix-hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "mix-prod": "npm run mix-production",
    "mix-production": "mix --production --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@css-render/vue3-ssr": "^0.15.12",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.5",
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.1",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
    "@inertiajs/server": "^0.1.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^5.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-css-modules-transform": "^1.6.2",
    "babel-plugin-file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.19.4",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "postcss-aspect-ratio-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-css-variables": "^0.19.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^9.3.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-critical": "^1.0.13",
    "sass": "^1.68.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "terser": "^5.26.0",
    "vike": "^0.4.147",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-html-purgecss": "^0.1.1",
    "vite-plugin-ssr": "^0.4.142",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-loader": "^16.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^3",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown": "2",
    "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.11",
    "@mdi/js": "^7.3.67",
    "@silvermine/videojs-airplay": "^1.3.0",
    "@silvermine/videojs-chromecast": "^1.5.0",
    "@silvermine/videojs-quality-selector": "^1.3.1",
    "@splidejs/vue-splide": "^0.6.12",
    "@videojs/themes": "^1.0.1",
    "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.3.4",
    "@vueuse/components": "^10.5.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.5.0",
    "clientjs": "^0.2.1",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "flag-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "javascript-time-ago": "^2.5.9",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "mitt": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "swiper": "^10.3.1",
    "ua-parser-js": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "v-phone-input": "^4.1.0",
    "vanilla-sharing": "^6.1.2",
    "video.js": "^8.6.1",
    "videojs-hotkeys": "^0.2.28",
    "videojs-mobile-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "videojs-seek-buttons": "^4.0.3",
    "vite-ssr": "^0.17.1",
    "vue-advanced-cropper": "^2.8.8",
    "vue-clipboard3": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-dragscroll": "^4.0.5",
    "vue-snap": "^1.0.0-alpha.5",
    "vue-timeago3": "^2.3.1",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.3.1",
    "vue3-youtube": "^0.1.9",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0",
    "vuetify-pro-tiptap": "^2.3.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "ziggy-js": "^1.8.1"
  }
}

